# How can I load storyboard programmatically from class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, xib

My problem is that I was looking for way to use both **storyboard** and **xib**. But I can't find proper way to load and show storyboard programmatically. Project was started developing with xib, and now it's very hard to nest all xib files in storyboard. So I was looking a way to do it in code, like with `alloc, init, push` for viewControllers. In my case I have only one controller in storyboard: `UITableViewController`, which has static cells with some content I want to show. If anyone knows proper way to work both with xib and storyboard without huge refactoring, I will appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 386, accepted):

In your storyboard go to the Attributes inspector and set the view controller's Identifier. You can then present that view controller using the following code.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: `[sb instantiateInitialViewController]` is handy if you want to start on the scene's default view controller.

Comment: James, thank you! I've been searching for quite some time trying to figure out how to instantiate a Storyboard's view. Your answer (and kokoko's question) are most refreshing to find.

Comment: On James Beith's code, one must reuse that UIViewControler *vc if it is switched back and forth with the current viewcontroller.  I found out the hard way that the vc sticks around and is wired to the storyboard nib until the user presses a button on the new view, and there is now a memory leak with that discarded vc from the prior incantations of this code.

Comment: In case anyone wants to know how to do this in the app delegate, you replace the `[self presentViewcontroller]` logic with these lines in the following order: 1) `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];` 2) `self.window.rootViewController = vc;` and 3) `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`. You can also probably get rid of the `modalTransitionStyle` line because this isn't a modal transition from the app delegate.

Comment: FYI, if you want to "push" the new storyboard instead of modally popping up, look at chaithraVeeresh's answer.

Comment: Remember to cast the view controller to your view controller class if you want to set any params which you'd normally do in prepareForSegue.

Comment: How to call the cocoa touch class file for that ViewController

Answer (score 86):

## Swift 3

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController")
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

## Swift 2

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController")
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

**Prerequisite**

Assign a *Storyboard ID* to your view controller.

[image: Storyboard ID]

*IB > Show the Identity inspector > Identity > Storyboard ID*

**Swift (legacy)**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController") as? UIViewController
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

*Edit: Swift 2 suggested in a comment by [Fred A.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552730/fred-a)*

if you want to use without any navigationController you have to use like following :

```
    let Storyboard  = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewController")
    present(vc , animated: true , completion: nil)
```

Comment: In Swift 2, you don't need to add "as? UIViewController", the compiler determines it automatically

Comment: or you can just do `self.storyboard` and merge line1&2

Answer (score 18):

In attribute inspector give the identifier for that view controller and the below code works for me

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:vc];
```

Comment: Use this if you are not using a UINavigationController as shown in other answers

Answer (score 2):

in swift
**NavigationController** and **pushController** you can replace for

```
present(vc, animated:true , completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

For **swift 4 and 5**, you can do this. Good practice is set name of Storyboard equal to StoryboardID.

```
enum StoryBoardName{
   case second = "SecondViewController"
}
extension UIStoryboard{
   class func load(_ storyboard: StoryBoardName) -> UIViewController{
      return UIStoryboard(name: storyboard.rawValue, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboard.rawValue)
   }
}
```

and then you can load your Storyboard in your ViewController like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController{
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let vc = UIStoryboard.load(.second) as? SecondViewController else {return}
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
```

}

When you create a new Storyboard just set the same name on StoryboardID and add Storyboard name in your enum "**StoryBoardName**"

Answer (score 1):

You can always jump right to the root controller:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

The extension below will allow you to load a `Storyboard` and it's associated `UIViewController`. Example: If you have a `UIViewController` named `ModalAlertViewController` and a storyboard named "ModalAlert"  e.g.

```swift
let vc: ModalAlertViewController = UIViewController.loadStoryboard("ModalAlert")
```

Will load both the `Storyboard` and `UIViewController` and `vc` will be of type `ModalAlertViewController`. **Note** Assumes that the storyboard's Storyboard ID has the same name as the storyboard and that the storyboard has been marked as *Is Initial View Controller*.

```swift
extension UIViewController {
    /// Loads a `UIViewController` of type `T` with storyboard. Assumes that the storyboards Storyboard ID has the same name as the storyboard and that the storyboard has been marked as Is Initial View Controller.
    /// - Parameter storyboardName: Name of the storyboard without .xib/nib suffix.
    static func loadStoryboard<T: UIViewController>(_ storyboardName: String) -> T? {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
        if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardName) as? T {
            vc.loadViewIfNeeded() // ensures vc.view is loaded before returning
            return vc
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```