# Changing view from xib to storyboard

Tags: storyboard, xib

I have a Storyboard project witch i need to have an xib file loading on startup, to show a login screen. Its based on a UIWindow and a view controller so i dont get it to work in storyboard. Anyways is there anyway that after this xib is loaded at start to push the view in to story board?

the storyboard is Tabbarbased if i does any difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would solve your problem : [How can I load storyboard programmatically from class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896406/how-can-i-load-storyboard-programmatically-from-class)

It is definitely possible.