# programmatic storyboard for universal iOS 6 app

Tags: ios, storyboard

**update 1**

[image: Attributes inspector]

**update 1**

**update 0**

[image: Execution aborts when I implement the code suggested in the answer provided].

**update 0**

[This fine question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896406/) does not quite deal with my Universal app which had both a iPhone and iPad xibs and now wants to use a storyboard.

This is the xib based BSAppDelegate.m (before storyboard)

```
    #import "BSAppDelegate.h"
    #import "BSViewController.h"

    @implementation BSAppDelegate

    NSString *receivedData;

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        // return YES;
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            self.viewController = [[BSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BSViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        } else {        
            self.viewController = [[BSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BSViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;   
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

I have tried to insert the following code right after the `else` above but I cannot quite complete the code fix which needs to set `self.viewController` to be compatible with the above code.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BSViewController"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Can you show me how to fix my code, please? I am using Xcode 4.5.2 and developing for iOS 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two issues:

1. just set self.ViewController to your vc which you get from the storyboard :)

   ```
       #import "BSAppDelegate.h"
   #import "BSViewController.h"

   @implementation BSAppDelegate

   NSString *receivedData;

   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
   {
       // Override point for customization after application launch.
       // return YES;
       self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
       // Override point for customization after application launch.
       if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
           self.viewController = [[BSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BSViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
       } else {        
           UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
           UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BSViewController"];
           vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
           self.viewController = (id)vc;
       }
       self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;   
       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
       return YES;
   }
   ```
2. in your storyboard, you have no identifier named 'BSViewController' set so the call instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier will fail. set the identifier (aka the Storyboard ID) visible in your screenshot

Comment: Updated my question with a image showing the termination message. Please take a look. Your answer looks right, so maybe I have not followed your answer correctly.

Comment: well the error states the storyboard doesn't contain a BSViewController. .... but you try to reference it in your question -- the storyboard seems wrong

Comment: you have to set tge identifier on the VC you want to reference! (in IB)

Comment: id say, click on the first VC (in your image) go to the inspector open the third tab (on the right) and fill out the identifier textbox with 'BSViewController'

Comment: My image is showing the open third tab (Identity inspector) filled out as you say, isn't it? I am going to add another image from the (fourth) Attributes inspector in case that tells something.

Comment: ah sorry its the storyboard id you have to set thats whats the identifier is called today

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't know where to set that, other than naming the file `MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard`.

Comment: I added this comment before your last, but it does not show. I thought I had tried before to change the "Identifier" in this line `UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainStoryboard_iPad"];`, but now it works fine. Anyhow, thanks. That seems to be working. Next I need to post another question about how to handle an `OverlayViewController` which was done as its own nib before, but now I have its overlaid view controller in the storyboard. Stay tuned.