# Replacing initWithNibName:bundle: call to use a storyboard instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard, nib

This code, using a xib, is working perfectly without any errors or exceptions.

```
- (id)initWithPageNumber:(int)page
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self !=nil)
    {
        pageNumber = page;
        NSLog(@"=====%@",pageNumberLabel);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then I tried this code using storyboards, and I got an exception

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Balu/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/973E52E9-0923-49A0-B4A6-212BC5F367CD/scrollpages.app> (loaded)' with name 'MyViewController''
```

Can anyone explain to me how to write this line of code for use with a storyboard?

```
self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: You are trying to load a view controller from storyboard and it has been already answered in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896406/how-can-i-load-storyboard-programmatically-from-class

Comment: i'll followed the link what you are send to me its not helpfull.

Comment: Are you sure you set Storyboard ID for your view controller?

Comment: ya i set the storyboard id. how to initialise above if condition following your link

Comment: The init method used by storyboard based controllers is initWithCoder:

Comment: @Balu `self = ...` line should be something like this: `self =  [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];`