# Objective-C: How to make a button take you to another class/storyboard

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

I want to make the bottom button seen in the storyboard on the right to take the user to the signupstoryboard.storyboard/signupController seen on the left when the user taps on the button. How can that be done?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qzKIzdW.png]

[image: Error]

```
{ - (IBAction)signupbutton:(id)sender; SignupController *signUpView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"signup"]; [self presentViewController:signUpView animated:YES completion:nil]; }
```

Comment: By code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896406/how-can-i-load-storyboard-programmatically-from-class

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code in a question. Just copy and past the code. I can barely read the code in that screenshot.

Comment: @Larme How exactly does this help me? The dude doesn't pick a specific button to take him to a storyboard, he just names a storyboard to transition to another storyboard. I could use some help, I'm new on objective-c

Comment: YOU STRUCTURED THE METHOD ALL WRONG.

Comment: woaah dude.. woaaaaah dude aight. what's wrong with it?

Comment: `- (IBAction)signupbutton:(id)sender
{
SignUpController *signUpView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"signup"];
[self presentViewController:signUpView animated:YES completion:nil];
}`

Comment: Replace your entire method starting from `{ - (IBAction)` with my version

Comment: @InfinityJames Thanks. This did not give me any errors. However it gives me  Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT .....  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it by code.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped
{
    NSString *storyboardName = @"signupstoryboard";
    UIViewController *nextViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
    // if you are using a navigation controller to push it:
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
    // otherwise if you are presenting it modally:
    [self presentViewController:nextViewController animated:YES completion:nil]    
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I want it to go to the next view controller when I specifically click the bottom button which is named signupButton. Basically when I tap that, I want it to take me to the signup page which is a separate controller/storyboard

Comment: Yeah... hook up that button to the above method (switch the storyboard name with the actual name though obviously).

Comment: well here's my code and it gives me an error "expected expression"                                {
        - (IBAction)signupbutton:(id)sender;
    SignupController *signUpView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"signup"];
    [self presentViewController:signUpView animated:YES completion:nil];
        
    }

Comment: Has the view controller actually got the Storyboard ID "signup"?

Comment: Have you debugged `storyboard` to check it is a valid object (and points to the correct storyboard)?

Comment: yeah, I have and it launches properly. But when I add the code above to the  implementation, it says "expected expression"

Comment: Copy the full exception into a comment.

Comment: Your method is completely wrong. Look at my method and then yours and look at the structural differences,

Comment: yes bud, but the thing is that the error isn't at the part we have different. The error is at the -(IBAction)buttontapped!

Answer (score 0):

In your .m (at the top)

```
#import "signupController.h"
```

In your button action method (Don't forget to set the storyboard id for your signupController as signup

```
- (IBAction)signupbutton:(id)sender
{
    SignupController *signUpView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"signup"]; [self presentViewController:signUpView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Thats it

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but when I do that my app gives me SIGABRT and the app crashes...

Comment: The error isn't at your code. It's at this part: - (IBAction)signupbutton:(id)sender; it says "expected expression"

Comment: @RobertVanGilder Check your button connection at the Connections Inspector in signupstoryboard. It should have only 1 touchUpInside event connection to you `signupbutton` method

Comment: It does have one touchupinside. But the thing is, I want to connect the LoginStoryboard which has a "signup" button with the SignupStoryboard when the signup button within the loginstoryboard is tapped...

Comment: Take a screenshot of your error and update it in your question. That will give me get a better idea of the problem you're getting

Comment: your signupbutton method should not be inside other methods as well

Comment: Where did you place the signupbutton method in you code

Comment: Right. I did what you said. I fixed it, placed it outside as its own method. It launches, but the program crashes. and gives me SIGABRT