# Load the tableview in another viewcontroller's view

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, interface-builder

Is there any way to load a uitableview from a storyboard?

[image: storyboard image]

Such as the Table View in my image.

What I did is:
 `self.view addSubView:vc.view` not worked.

**I want to load the tableview in another viewcontroller's view.**
thanks in advance!

Comment: do `self.addSubViewController:vc` before `self.view.addSubView:vc.view`. And in storyboard you can drag `containerView`, it will do the job automatically for you

Comment: You would also need to load the Storyboard first if it is by itself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896406/how-can-i-load-storyboard-programmatically-from-class shows how to load a storyboard programmatically.

Comment: thanks,it works! self.addSubViewController:vc.