# How can I transition back to a VC from a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have a baseVC and a navigation controller.

The navigation controller has a bar button item, which i gave a segue to go back to the BaseVC.

Unfortunately when I press the done button to return to the BaseVC (the initial state from which I went to the navigation controller), the baseVC ends up having the top look as if I went to the extra options navigationVC (a VC which shows more info on content in cells in the main navigation controller)

**How can I prevent this?**

This is done on the interface builder.

### Update:

I have found that my issue is [related to this one...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31310241/stop-navigation-controller-from-affecting-other-view-controllers?rq=1)

Comment: A screenshot would surely be a big help. :)

Comment: You need to use an unwind segue. It sounds like you are pushing a new instance of the basevc onto the navigation stack

Comment: @Paulw11 how do I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for back to root viewController use

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

for back to previous viewController use

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: The baseVC is not embedded in the navigation controller so this did not work.