# Is it possible to reference other Storyboards within Storyboards?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, interface-builder

I am working on an iOS app and I want to split it into a couple of Storyboards, the problem is that I can't seem to figure out a way to setup references between Storyboards as an entry point.

For example I want my `Main.storyboard` to look something like this:

`--> Authentication Storyboard --> Tabbed Storyboard --> ...`

I am new to iOS development and I would expect this to be simple, but can't seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: you want more than one storyboard, like Login.storyboard, Main.storyboard, and you are confused how to call Controllers from different storyboards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use multiple Storyboards in a project BUT No, you cant reference them directly from inside another storyboard.

**Referencing a Storyboard to use on launch**

Your project target can use any of the storyboards contained within it. The reference for the storyboard entry point can be found in the target settings.

[image]

1. Select the target
2. Select the General Tab
3. In the dropdown for main interface select which storyboard to use initially.

**Referencing a Storyboard in code**

So in this example I wish to push a viewcontroller onto a navigation Controller. The viewcontroller I want to reference may be in a different storyboard or the current one I'm using. The code doesn't care...

```
    if let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "A2ndStoryboard", bundle: nil) {
      if let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SomeViewController" as String) {

        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
      }
    }
```

When you want to reference ViewControllers like this you need to ensure that they are identified in the Storyboard correctly:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I had the wrong Idea that Main storyboard is required to be starting point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use multiple storyboards. use one storyboard with multiple `viewcontrollers` with `segue` between them and `embed` `navigationcontroller`. for exa, use one viewcontroller for  Authentication like wise another viewcontroller for tabs (tabbarviewcontroller). give segue from authenticationVC to tabbarVC. hope this will help. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you say you're new to iOS development let me try to recap this for you:

**Interface Builder** (IB) is a tool built in to Xcode that helps you design your user interface without any code. Everything IB can do can also be done programmatically. IB supports two different types of files: XIB files and Storyboards.

**XIB** files (extension `.xib`) are collections of `UIView` objects that you can design using IB.

**Storyboards** (extension `.storyboard`) are collections of `UIViewController` objects which all have a `view` property that you can design using IB.

**Conlusion**:
There (currently) is no such thing as an Interface Builder file type which represents a collection of XIBs or Storyboards. Therefore ***you can't reference a Storyboard within a Storyboard as of now***. Instead you can still split your view controllers up into different Storyboards and transition between them *programmatically*.

Here's another thread on SO to **help you get started** with the programmatic transitions:

[How can I load storyboard programmatically from class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896406/how-can-i-load-storyboard-programmatically-from-class)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this breakdown, it has helped me to better understand how the storyboards are supposed to work. The accepted answer had a concrete solution and that is why I accepted it, though I would accept both.