# Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle ··· with name 'chosenCountry''

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want touch the `UIBarButtonItem` in the top right, and push a new viewController. So, the code is:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                              target:self
                              action:@selector(insertNewObject)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

and method `insertNewObject` is:

```
-(void)insertNewObject{
    chosenViewController *chosenCountry = [[chosenViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"chosenCountry" bundle:nil];
    //self.chosenViewController = chosenCountry;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:chosenCountry animated:YES];
}
```

but XCode have a error when I run  'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle ...(loaded)' with name 'chosenCountry''
How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a xib file named `chosenCountry`?

Comment: i think your viewconrtoller name is  chosenViewController.try this chosenViewController

Comment: @Larme I don't know,I drag a new view controller in storyboard and set it's class at  chosenViewController.What should I do?thank you very much

Comment: Then, it's related to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896406/how-can-i-load-storyboard-programmatically-from-class ?

Comment: @MAuLIK if change it to chosenViewController,Xcode even don't let me run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
 UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chosenCountry"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Welcome @Shucheng :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added your vc in storyboard, hence `initWithNibName` will not work.

Either use `segue` or use storyboard's method [`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:) to instantiate the view controller

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it works for you

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
yourViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chosenCountry"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Yeah! It work with me,but Bhadresh Mulsaniyaa answered first,sorry :)