# in swift, ViewController wont let me access its textfield from another class

Tags: swift, cocoa

here is what is happening https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK0AF.jpg

yes i've read the article about optional

but that textfield isn't nil or without a value as it does it
when i press enter when theres a value in the text-bar
i also tried ! and ? with same results

i tried many many things and it wont work
always the same crash

can someone explain what is the reason that textfield is hard to access

i tried

```
var = ViewControler()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the class function from the viewcontroller that contains the textfield change the class function to have one argument :

```
func changetextfieldincontroller(_ vc: NSViewController){
   if let vc = vc as? ViewController{ 
     vc.textField.stringValue = "New text"
   }
}
```

when you call it from the controller make sure to pass self as an argument.

Comment: it says Value of type 'NSViewController' has no member 'textField'

Comment: when i try to call the funcion it says Missing argument for parameter #1 in call    updateclass().changetextfieldincontroller()

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the viewController since it looks like it's from a storyboard/xib. If that's the case, you can check this other question: [How can I load storyboard programmatically from class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896406/how-can-i-load-storyboard-programmatically-from-class)

Comment: i read it but this is for swift 3.0 and im using swift 4.0 and none of the nswers suit my problem

Comment: Swift 3.0 and swift 4.0 don't have a lot of difference when it comes to instantiating your storyboard/xib. Are you using storyboard/xib?

Comment: i can't understand why the textfield isnt accessible , i dont get the whole its not loaded part, it is when i run that function in that other class

Comment: The items inside your ViewController is not loaded because of your storyboard. The Storyboard need to be instantiated in order for the items inside the viewController to actually exist.

Comment: what is the easiest way to do in swift 4.0?