# Xcode Launch Animation Storyboard Issue

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm very very new to swift, and xcode. I've recently have been trying to create a app for fun...

What I am trying to achieve : (**App Launch** Logo Animation that after app is loaded it will take you to the home **storyboard**). I recently took a look at [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbGsI5O9rWY&t=577s) It sort of confused me because my home story board is not loading correctly.

I would have to guess this is happening because the Story Board, `HomeViewController` is just loading a black screen? I want it to be loading my "Home **Storyboard**" that I made.

My Launch Setup :
[image]
My Home Setup (what I want it to load into) notice I did change the class :
[image]

Code For Launch / View Controller :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
        lazy var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,width:150,height:150))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "RobloxStudio")
        return imageView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        imageView.center = view.center
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.5, execute: {
            self.animate()
        })
    }

    private func animate(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            let size = self.view.frame.size.width * 2
            let diffX = size - self.view.frame.size.width
            let diffY = self.view.frame.size.height - size

            self.imageView.frame = CGRect(
                x: -(diffX/2),
                y: diffY/2,
                width: size,
                height: size
            )
        })

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
            self.imageView.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { done in
            if done{
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
                    let viewController = HomeViewController()
                    viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
                    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                    self.present(viewController, animated: true)
                })
            }
        })


    }
}
```

Code For HomeViewController :

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Is there any simpler way to make a launch animation, and to make it load into my story board that already has the designs? Any tips?

Comment: You need to load your HomeViewController from the storyboard, this should point you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/a/32274363/5508175

Comment: @Andrew looking at the post, where would the following code go for the solution answer? Still quite confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first need to add a storyboard id to your `HomeViewController` in the storyboard, by convention you usually use the name of the view controller, so your storyboard id would be `"HomeViewController"`

So in the box highlighted in red, enter the text `"HomeViewController"`:

[image]

Once you have done that then you need to instantiate it. You would change the following code in your `ViewController` from this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
    let viewController = HomeViewController()
    viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(viewController, animated: true)
})
```

To this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
    viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(viewController, animated: true)
})
```

In this code we first find the `UIStoryboard` called `"Main"`

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

We then look for the storyboard that has the same `identifier` that we set in the storyboard, in this case `"HomeViewController"`

```
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
```

Then finally we set the `modalTransitionStyle` and `modalPresentationStyle` on the viewController, before we present it.

```
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Very well written, thank you very much.

Comment: Yet this did get to fix the viewing board problem. It seems to not do the launch animation if the class Is "HomeViewController" instead of "ViewController". What could be the problem there?

Comment: You need two view controllers in your Main storyboard. One that uses ViewController and is your initial view controller for the storyboard, and another that is your HomeViewController. I suggest you watch the tutorial again and follow it exactly. Once you are comfortable with it, try editing it to do what you want.

Comment: Alright thank you the information. Just checking the "Main" storyboard though would have class ```HomeViewController``` and so for the storyboard id correct?

What happens is it, does the animation but then breaks/errors. Says "Could not cast value of type 'Roblox_Learning.ViewController'"

Comment: There should only be two view controllers inside your storyboard file. One called `ViewController` which is the initial view controller in the storyboard where the animation starts from. And one called `HomeViewController` where it ends. Both of these view controllers should be in the Main storyboard. Both should have identifiers that match their class name.